# Another random number per every thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have simple class to generating random numbers:

```
public class Bar
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    public int GenerateRandomNumber()
    {
        return rnd.Next(1, 100);
    }
}
```

Then I use it in second class, where I'm creating two thread. Every thread is writing on console own id and random number by using function from bar class. It looks like below:

```
public class Foo
{
    Thread t1;
    Thread t2;
    Bar bar;
    public Foo(Bar bar)
    {
        t1 = new Thread(GetRandomNumber);
        t2 = new Thread(GetRandomNumber);
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
    }

    private void GetRandomNumber()
    {   
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,bar.GenerateRandomNumber());
    }
}
```

So in main I have:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Bar bar1 = new Bar();
    Bar bar2 = new Bar();

    Foo f1 = new Foo(bar1);
    Foo f2 = new Foo(bar2);

    f1.Start();
    f2.Start();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In console I can get for example somethink like:

```
Thread 11 34
Thread 12 9
Thread 13 34
Thread 14 9
```

My question is what can I do to get another numbers per every thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize random generator with so called `seed`  the is different for different threads. The simplest way would be:

```
Random rnd = new Random(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
```

**UPDATE**
In code you've posted simple changing of one line won't help.
In order to it working you'll have to change it in the way so that every thread has it's own `Random` instance. That would be something like:

```
public class Foo
{
    Thread t1;
    Thread t2;     
    public Foo(Func<Bar> getBar)
    {
        t1 = new Thread(()=>GetRandomNumber(getBar()));
        t2 = new Thread(()=>GetRandomNumber(getBar()));
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
    }

    private void GetRandomNumber(Bar bar)
    {   
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,bar.GenerateRandomNumber());
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo f1 = new Foo(()=>new Bar());
    Foo f2 = new Foo(()=>new Bar());

    f1.Start();
    f2.Start();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Random rnd = new Random();`, the seed for random number generator is initialized based on system clock.  The resolution of that clock isn't all that fine (I don't remember the frequency, but it is less than 100 ticks per second I believe).  So both of your threads create in instance of `Random` at the same time using system clock, and thus both have the same seed.

Seed is what determines the sequence of pseudo-random numbers that it'll generate.  Since both threads get same seed, you get both to produce the same sequence.

Best solution is to only create instance of one `Random` object and pass it to your threads (and possibly protect access to it, since I'm not sure if it is MT-safe).

Another one is to provide some other seed generator instead of default one, such as couple system time with thread id or similar mesh (note that just managed thread id as seed might not be enough since managed thread ids typically tend to hang in lower ranges and thus your random seeds will be very predictable, and thus not at all random).